# Ubuntu 20.04 : Virtualbox 6.1.16 is shown but apt policy virtualbox says no

Tags: 20.04

[image: image shows discrepancy between 2 infos]Apart from the now known issue about installing Virtualbox on Ubuntu 20.04 due to kernel 5.8.0.36 incompatobility with Vbox dkms building, I have this quite strange situation where Terminal entry ''apt policy virtualbox'' responds ''no version installed'' while I have the Virtualbox icon on my favorites, can open it (while unable to use it) and is listed in the computer apps.
Any explanation ?

Comment: apt policy virtualbox-6.1 (just different package names)

Comment: Try `dpkg -l | grep -i virtualbox` .

Comment: @adasiko You should write that up as an answer.  =)

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same situation, but this is probably because I did not use `apt` to install VirtualBox. Instead I [downloaded the `.deb` file](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and installed it that way.

[image: VirtualBox when None Installed]

Perhaps you did the same a while back and forgot?

Comment: Thank's for your reply... but I do not think It has any link for I did try to install Vbox using all possibles ways : command line and using synaptics another time and using Ubuntu software. At the end I've allways got the same issue.